# Collecting Real Estate Data in the US

Tags: usa, real-estate

I have seem some related questions but none of them seem to have the answer I am looking for. I want to be able to find a website (say like the Multiple Listing Service listings) that would allow me to scrape data from their site about property sales records. In particular, for a given zip code I would like to be able to aggregate purchase histories such as number of houses sold in a particular month and year, and prices (during that month and year) in which the houses sold.  Does a website with this type of data to be collected exist?

Comment: Does it have to be a website? Scraping sites will often be in violation of copyright ([That does not make your question invalid here](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/336/are-webscraping-data-on-topic), but it may not be the wise thing to do).

Comment: @JanDoggen it does not have to be a website.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the property appraiser's office for each county to assemble the data for free. Anything above this level is going to be a cost item.

For example, the Polk County Property Appraiser's office has the [Appraisal Data](ftp://ftp.polkpa.org/AppraisalData) and the [GIS Data at the Parcel Level](ftp://ftp.polkpa.org/GISData). The Appraisal Data includes the sales database from which to pull your data.

Comment: Great answer. FYI, this dataset might be called the assessor's roll, or the auditor data, or something else depending on the county.

Answer (score 3):

Daniel Miller's answer recommending property appraiser's offices is great, and if your need is confined to a couple of counties, it's not too much work to locate each dataset. However, if you need this information on a nationwide basis, hunting down every single appraiser's data is incredibly tedious.

An alternative is something like the [Zillow API](http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/APIOverview.htm). Zillow has real estate data for the entirety of the U.S., and in my experience it's pretty solid data. They have rate-limits and terms of use limiting what you can do with their API, but their data is very good (and is usually sourced from those property appraisers).

Comment: Thanks Hayden, I keep forgetting about the Zillow API as it is a commercial source. It is a great resource.